# finding maximum of a function with varying domain

Tags: calculus

I ran into this problem recently:

You are  given the function $f(x) = x^2 + (n - 1 - x)^2$ defined on the closed interval $[0, n-1]$. Find the maximum value of this function by providing an or more $(x_{max}, f(x_{max}))$ pairs.

My understanding so far is to proceed like I would in Calc 2, finding f', getting critical points, plugging in those values in f, etc. My work so far:

$f'(x) = 4x-2n+2$
$f'(x) = 0$ when $x = (n-1)/2$

$f((n-1)/2) = 2((n-1)/2)^2$

This is where I get stuck; is this an answer? I'm not sure where the domain upper bound of n-1 even plays into this. I'm not familiar with the concept of a varying domain.

Comment: Please use Mathjax from next time. I edited the post for you.

Comment: You do not need to worry about the varying domain so much. Since $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is in the interval, you will have found a local extremum.You should compare the value you have to that at the endpoints, since thats the only other place you could have a max or a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **defined on** the closed interval [0,n−1]

The words "defined on" in this problem signify that the *domain* of the function $f(x)$ is $[0,n-1]$. The value you arrived at for $x_{max}=(n-1)/2$  belongs to this domain. Hence, there is no need to worry.

Remember that we cannot comment about the validity of the $y$ value $=f(x_{max})$ as long as we don't know the *codomain*.

**Remark:** you did not check the sign of $f''(x)$. But it turns out this did not matter since the question is asking you a maximum and there is *only one* extremum. So, that extremum *must be* a maximum. (if the question is assumed correct that is)

Comment: Apparently the endpoints are the maxima, just tried them and they ended up having a greater value than the critical point I found. Regardless, thank you for the reminders on properly calculating extrema.

Comment: @Muffinman. You are correct since $f''(x)=4$

Comment: @Muffinman You are correct, as Claude noted. In fact, you can also see that the given $f(x)$ is a quadratic with coefficient of $x^2>0$, so it's only extremum will definitely be a _minimum_.

Answer (score 0):

One of the methods used out there is by applying the CS inequality $A^2 +B^2 \ge \dfrac{(A+B)^2}{2}$ with equality occurs at $A = B$.  Apply this inequality with $A = x, B = n-1 - x$ to find the min and where it happens. Is that helpful?

Comment: Very much so, thanks!